# Wordpress theme options variable scope

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I have my theme options saved and in my functions.php file, I have:

```
$my_option = get_option('theme_options');
```

So, if in functions.php I insert:

```
echo $my_option['name'];
```

It will echo correctly. However, if I put the same echo line anywhere else in any other theme file, it will not work.

The only way I have been able to get it to work is if I put:

```
global $my_option;
```

at the top of every single file. I have seen many other themes that didn't need to do this. Why can't I get the theme options variable to work throughout my theme?

Comment: First - it is not reccomanded to call %option with a name like "theme_options" . You should think of a more distinguished name that will avoid conflicts .

Second - your theme related $options will work only on the theme where they were defined .
(and BTW - what do you mean by "anywhere else" - is that anywhere else in your theme ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Open your functions.php file and at the very top globalize the variable e.g:

```
<?php 
global $my_option;
```

and this should be available anywhere in your theme files as log as you are not inside a function, if that is the case then you will have to globalize it again inside the function.